# How can I read Drag location in ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I am trying to read **location** in DragGesture of a View connected to a ScrollView, but ScrollView take control of DragGesture on all view and does not let me to read those information.
Here is my example to show the issue,
**My Goal** is reading the Drag location in DragGesture.

using new code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var locationY: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {                
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Color.black.frame(height: 300)
                }
                .gesture( DragGesture().onChanged { value in locationY = value.location.y; print(locationY)} )
                

                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        Color.blue.frame(height: 300)
                    }.background(GeometryReader {
                        Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                                               value: $0.frame(in: .global).origin.y)
                        // value: $0.frame(in: .named("scroll_area")).origin.y)
                    })
                }
                // .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll_area")
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) {
                    self.locationY = $0
                    print(">> offset: \($0)")
                }
                .frame(height: 300)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
    
struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible solution, to use `GeometryReader` in background to read rect of view (in any needed coordinate space) and view preferences to pass needed coordinate at top level.

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

*Note: commented variant is for superview (ie. ScrollView) coordinates*

```
    ScrollView
    {
        VStack
        {
            Color.blue.frame(height: 300)
             }.background(GeometryReader {
                  Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                        value: $0.frame(in: .global).origin.y)
                        // value: $0.frame(in: .named("scroll_area")).origin.y)
             })
    }
    // .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll_area")
         .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) {
            self.locationY = $0
            print(">> offset: \($0)")
        }
```

and helper preference key

```
struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: to Asperi: I used your code in update, but I do get deferent value for same drag in witness View, how I could use your code to get same answer like witness

Comment: Drag gesture by default uses `.local` coordinate space, if I correctly understood you.

Comment: yes, you are right, the deference is on dragging on black rec would give the right value of location inside rec, for example if I tap and drag to top it would give 0 until down 300, but I can not get same value for blue one with your code, thanks a lot for your help even to this point